# Passing variable into catch() exception

Tags: esp8266, ntpclient

I'm working with a try{} catch(){} exception right now and I want to change a Variable. For this my board has to connect to the Internet and with a try{} statement it will try to do so. If it fails I simply want to set the variables to 0.

```
  try {
    timeClient.update();
    ntp_seconds  = timeClient.getSeconds();
    ntp_minutes = timeClient.getMinutes();
    ntp_hours = timeClient.getHours();
  } 
    catch () {
     ntp_seconds = 0;
     ntp_minutes = 0;
     ntp_hours = 0;
  }
```

I am getting this error: Compilation error: expected type-specifier before ')' token
I know that I somehow have to pass my variables into the catch() "function" but somehow I can't pass variables in like I would with normal functions.

Comment: This try/catch construct won't work with Arduino C++ :  https://forum.arduino.cc/t/try-catch/180063

Comment: OK. There is little more to say so I'll present that as the answer.

Comment: Besides that, why do you think that the NTP client is going to throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refresh your knowledge about the `try`-`catch` statement by reading the respective chapter in your C++ book.

You need to declare an exception parameter in `catch`, which you can ignore:

```cpp
  try {
    timeClient.update();
    ntp_seconds  = timeClient.getSeconds();
    ntp_minutes = timeClient.getMinutes();
    ntp_hours = timeClient.getHours();
  } 
  catch (exception& ignored) {
    ntp_seconds = 0;
    ntp_minutes = 0;
    ntp_hours = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino IDE does not support the C++ try/catch exception handling construct and explicitly disables this feature.
See: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/try-catch/180063 for a fuller explanation.

Comment: how does IDE disable it? the build commands are in platform.txt of each platform. a forum post from 2013 is maybe outdated